# UK Visa plus Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, uk, schengen

Is it okay if I get a UK visa which is my first point of entry, and at the same time another visa which is a Schengen visa from France embassy?

This is because my first point of entry (UK) is not a Schengen member country.

Comment: no issue. treat both visa separately.

Comment: Point of entry to what? Schengen and UK are separate territories, with separate administration, they don't communicate (not for visa applications at least). There is no reason why you would need to worry about applying to both territories.

Comment: You appear to have asked to very similar questions only moments apart, do we need both of them or can we merge them into one single one?